# Facing issues while taking thumbnail from video in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

```
 let thumbnail = `${req.file.filename.split('.')[0]}.png`
        await ffmpeg(path.join(__dirname, `../../public/uploads/posts/${req.file.filename}`))
            .screenshots({
                filename: `${thumbnail}`,
                folder: path.join(__dirname, `../../public/uploads/posts`),
                count: 1,
                size: '320x240'
            });
```

And getting this issue

```
Error: Cannot find ffprobe
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\ffprobe.js:145:31
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:194:9
at wrapper (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:268:20)
at next (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4582:24)
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:321:20
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:186:13
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:123:9
at wrapper (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:268:20)
at next (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4582:24)
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:116:11
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\utils.js:223:16
at F (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\which\which.js:68:16)
at E (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
```

Emitted 'error' event on FfmpegCommand instance at:
at runCommand (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\recipes.js:345:21)
at wrapper (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:268:20)
at next (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4582:24)
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:321:20
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\recipes.js:177:15
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\recipes.js:162:11
at handleCallback (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\ffprobe.js:106:9)
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\ffprobe.js:145:16
at C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\capabilities.js:194:9
[... lines matching original stack trace ...]
at next (C:\Users\user\Documents\projects\stitchlr_web\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:4582:24)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't install ffmpeg. Install ffmpeg first

Answer (score 0):

use https://www.npmjs.com/package/thumbler
for generating thumbnail from video
it has support for window, linux, mac
other packages give some type of error related ffmpeg or has compatibility issue with other platforms